# What is the effect of a `section` command with an empty list of input sections in a GNU linker script?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, ld, linker-scripts

In an LD linker script I have the following fragment in the `SECTIONS` section:

```
. = (__BUFFER_LOCATION_); 
BUFFER . : { } > EXTERNAL_MEM
```

where `__BUFFER_LOCATION_` is defined to some address and `EXTERNAL_MEM` is defined in the `MEMORY` section.

In the `C` program, I have a global buffer declared as:

```
char outbuf[4096] __attribute__((section("BUFFER")));
```

It can be seen that the linker script does not mention any input section named `BUFFER`, but the output section is named as such.

When compiling the program I see that the linker placed the buffer in the supposed address (`BUFFER_LOCATION`), although the input section was not defined in the LDF. When I remove the `attribute` from the source, the buffer is placed in a completely different address.

So, I assume that by default, an output-section-command of type "input section description" adds the output section's name to the input sections list implicitly, unless defined somewhere else. However, reading [the manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/SECTIONS.html#SECTIONS), I could not find a description of such behaviour.

Did I miss something, or is it an "undocumented feature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an output section will automatically match input sections with the same name, unless a different output section mentions them explicitly.

This is documented under [Orphan Sections](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Orphan-Sections.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Orphan sections are sections present in the input files which are not explicitly placed into the output file by the linker script.** The
>   linker will still copy these sections into the output file by either
>   finding, or creating a suitable output section in which to place the
>   orphaned input section.
>
> **If the name of an orphaned input section exactly matches the name of
>   an existing output section, then the orphaned input section will be
>   placed at the end of that output section.**
>
> If there is no output section with a matching name then new output
>   sections will be created...